# "file" program and fifos

Tags: linux, file, unix, bsd

```
file <(echo "abcdefghijk")
```

It would be really cool if this could print something like "ASCII text", i.e. that `file` won't just give up and tell me it's a fifo.

Comment: And your question is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then mislead him:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijk" | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```